# MySQL Append results from query to current record?

Tags: mysql, join, append

I have a successful query that currently returns all data except for one table.  The last table contains meta data where it is a one to many relationship (one product, multiple records with related data).

Is there a way to append a field with a value to the end of an existing query so that I can still access the record set in PHP with a mysql_fetch_array() command?

essentially I want to query for any records with the product ID, and then append multiple additional fields.

After thinking about it i was actually wondering if I can include an array within the records set (i.e. the array of results for the meta data) and access that through PHP?

**Working Query:**

```
SELECT offers.*, c.short_name AS sponsorName, c.logo AS sponsorLogo 
FROM offers LEFT JOIN sponsors AS c ON c.id=offers.sponsor ORDER BY end_date ASC
```

**Results:**

```
ID: 43875
category: 1
state: CO
city: Denver
zip: 80221
sponsor: 1
title: The coolest thing ever
duration: 2 years
price: 10
frequency:: Month
```

**Second query that gets the right meta data-**

```
SELECT mo.`name` AS meta_value FROM offer_metas 
LEFT JOIN meta_options AS mo ON mo.id = offer_metas.meta_option 
WHERE offer_id='48735' ORDER BY meta_option ASC
```

**results:**

```
meta_value:
'5-10 tickets'
'General Admission'
```

I want to add those two fields to the record up top .. but don't know how to append all fields within a query result into a single already existing record.

**--SOLVED--**

**Query has been adjusted to account for GROUP_CONCAT as follows**

```
SELECT
offers.*,
s.short_name AS sponsorName,
s.logo AS sponsorLogo,
GROUP_CONCAT( mn.title) titles,
GROUP_CONCAT( mo.`name`) metas
FROM offers
LEFT JOIN sponsors AS s ON s.id = offers.sponsir
INNER JOIN offer_metas ON offer_metas.offer_id = offers.id
INNER JOIN meta_options as mo ON offer_metas.meta_option = mo.id
INNER JOIN meta_names as mn ON mo.category = mn.category AND mo.cat_seq = mn.seq
ORDER BY end_date ASC
```

**data results looked good including 2 fields called "titles" and "metas" that looked like this**

```
titles: 'Number of Tickets,Purchased Seats'
metas: '5-10,General Administration'
```

now THOSE .. I can work with in PHP .. and since they have the same number of elements i'll just parse them into an array i can better work with :)

Comment: I tried doing multiple left joins to accomplish this .. but it kept duplicating the product record for each "meta" value that i left joined ... trying to keep it in one record.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; the closest you might get is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the second query's results into a single record, then `explode` in PHP on the same delimiter.  On the other hand, if every record in the first query gives rise to the same number of records in the second, you *could* pivot the second query onto the end of the first (although since MySQL doesn't have any native support for pivoting, this would have to be a rather ugly manual hack) - but why do you want to do this?  What's wrong with the status quo?

Comment: mainly i want to display the results in a table .. and i can't set the php/html for column widths etc because there are columns for each of the meta data... :( ... if i have it all in one record .. problem solved.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Then maybe [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is exactly what you're after.

Comment: unfortunately the number of meta data canges for each query .. si could have 1 this time, 2 next time .. the meta_data is a one to namy table (one offer, multiple records containing the same "offer" and diferent "metadata")

Comment: ok .. i'll research group_concat

Comment: Remove solved from title and read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to your comments above, it sounds like [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will give you what you're after.  It won't return the `meta_values` as an array, but rather as a string (e.g. with each value separated by `<br/>` in order that they can be emitted directly as HTML):

```
SELECT
  offers.*,
  c.short_name AS sponsorName,
  c.logo AS sponsorLogo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(mo.name ORDER BY meta_option ASC SEPARATOR '<br/>') AS meta_values
FROM
  offers
  LEFT JOIN sponsors     AS c  ON c.id       = offers.sponsor
  LEFT JOIN offer_metas  AS o  ON o.offer_id = offers.id
  LEFT JOIN meta_options AS mo ON mo.id      = offer_metas.meta_option
ORDER BY end_date ASC;
```

Note that, if you need to escape the meta values for any HTML they might contain, you'll need to choose a different separator (perhaps [U+001E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e/index.htm), `INFORMATION SEPARATOR TWO`?) and have PHP replace that separator with suitable HTML after escaping any contained HTML.

Comment: yeah .. after doing a bit of reseach I have a final working query ..  changed the database a little .. but i'll add it to my solution above. Baically i will take the values of a given field and split it with PHP to get my colum nheaders and then do the same for the data columns .. "Brilliant" .. you guys rock!